# What is the base operating system for a gradle docker image?

Tags: docker, gradle, virtual-machine

In my Dockerfile I use: `FROM gradle:6.8.0-jdk11-hotspot`

I know that each docker container runs some kind of virtual machine. Thus it must have some operating system (earlier I used Alpine as base-image). Using the Gradle image as base I am unsure what OS my container is running. I suppose it's some standard since the Docker Hub page of the gradle image doesn't go into detail and gradle itself is no OS.

How can I determine the OS of some docker images when using them as a base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try pulling the image, running it, then use [some of the commands/steps for knowing what Linux version you are using](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23833/370183):

> Use the following commands to get more details:
>
> 1. `cat /etc/*release*`
> 2. `uname -a`

```
$ docker pull gradle:6.8.0-jdk11-hotspot
...
Digest: sha256:13e62bd49f58d62c65672d6dfdcb79de3ffac01be8551f1d5cf44937c0776f86
Status: Downloaded newer image for gradle:6.8.0-jdk11-hotspot
docker.io/library/gradle:6.8.0-jdk11-hotspot

~$ docker run -it gradle:6.8.0-jdk11-hotspot bash
root@09e06441cc17:/home/gradle# 
root@09e06441cc17:/home/gradle# uname -a
Linux 09e06441cc17 4.19.121-linuxkit #1 SMP Tue Dec 1 17:50:32 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@09e06441cc17:/home/gradle# 
root@09e06441cc17:/home/gradle# cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
```

It looks like it's based on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa).

You can also try tracking down the base image from the Dockerfile.

1. From the [gradle Dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/amd64/gradle/), there are links to each image tag's Dockerfile. The `6.8.0-jdk11-hotspot` links to [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/c618fa59f4cf872845a6f38bf7cce948fbf8dbc4/hotspot/jdk11/Dockerfile) with this `FROM` line:

   ```
   FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-hotspot
   ```
2. From the [adoptopenjdk Dockerhub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/adoptopenjdk), I could not find a clear link to the Dockerfile for the `adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-hotspot` version, but I think it is indeed Ubuntu as explained on the **Image Variants** section on that Dockerhub page:

   > Some of these tags may have names like focal in them. These are the suite code names for releases of Ubuntu and indicate which release the image is based on. If your image needs to install any additional packages beyond what comes with the image, you'll likely want to specify one of these explicitly to minimize breakage when there are new releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't Ubuntu somewhat bad to use as it is kind of large? Would it make more sense (space-wise) to use Alpine as base and installing gradle manually? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Felix It is larger compared to -alpine or -slim. But "good"/"bad" depends on your needs, if you are releasing an app image that's based on this image, if you have a CI/CD pipeline that builds images, if you don't have that much disk space, etc. Most images like this have this in the **Image Variants** section: "*This is the defacto image. If you are unsure about what your needs are, you probably want to use this one. It is designed to be used both as a throw away container (mount your source code and start the container to start your app), as well as the base to build other images off of.*"

Answer (score 1):

You can trace the `FROM` lines upwards until you find the ultimate base image.

1. [`gradle:6.8.0-jdk11-hotspot`'s Dockerfile](https://github.com/keeganwitt/docker-gradle/blob/c618fa59f4cf872845a6f38bf7cce948fbf8dbc4/hotspot/jdk11/Dockerfile) has:

   ```
   FROM adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-hotspot
   ```
2. [`adoptopenjdk:11-jdk-hotspot`'s Dockerfile](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/blob/a765cdfe876fd87610d256c7d056aa1f860b4f74/11/jdk/ubuntu/Dockerfile.hotspot.releases.full) has:

   ```
   FROM ubuntu:20.04
   ```

   [AdoptOpenJDK's documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/adoptopenjdk/README.md#adoptopenjdkversion) says:

   > Some of these tags may have names like focal in them. These are the suite code names for releases of [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and indicate which release the image is based on. If your image needs to install any additional packages beyond what comes with the image, you'll likely want to specify one of these explicitly to minimize breakage when there are new releases of Ubuntu.
3. [`ubuntu`'s Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu) shows that `20.04` is an alias for:

   > `20.04`, `focal-20201106`, `focal`, `latest`

---

> But isn't Ubuntu somewhat bad to use as it is kind of large? Would it make more sense (space-wise) to use Alpine as base and installing gradle manually?

Yes, Ubuntu is a large base image. Does AdoptOpenJDK need it or do they use it out of convenience? Perhaps Alpine is missing something they need; perhaps they require glibc and don't work with Alpine's musl replacement; perhaps they can't change it now since downstream images rely on Apt. I don't know.